# Previous sprite in paper2D flip book animation remains behind updated sprite animation

Tags: animation, sprite, unreal-engine4

I have been stuck on this issue for around a week now, I have tried searching around however I can't seem to find an conclusive fix to this issue. The imgur album and the link to the doc shows you the blueprint for the animations for the sprite and how it looks in game.

The sprite changes depending on how far away the player is away from the enemy.

Image of in-game and the enum switch node:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE1ck.jpg

Image of the Movement node:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx4VD3wkvXNVLVI0Y0RhSDhiYXc/view?usp=sharing

Sorry for the way the Doc blueprint looks. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys. I found out. By changing the papersprite character to a flipbook instead, I was able to cycle through the enums without error